# Hybridauth - Windows Live stopped importing contacts

Tags: hybridauth, windows-live

I'm not sure when it started, but Windows Live stopped returning contacts. Updating to version 2.10 did not help. The raw response for getUserContacts (Live.php) returns:

```
object(stdClass)#10 (1) { ["data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Any clue/suggestion is greatly appreciated.